# RHEL 7.6 - Built Python3.6 from Source Broke Network

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, centos, redhat

I have a RHEL system which by default was running Python2.7 and Python3.4

I needed Python3.6 for a project I wanted to work on and so I downloaded it and built it from source. I ran `make` and `make install` which hindsight may have been the wrong decision.

Now I do not seem to have any internet connectivity. Does anyone know what I may have over written to cause this or at least where specifically I can look to track this issue down?

Note: I can Putty into the Linux machine but it doesn't seem to have any other connectivity, specifically HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit weird that this would break network connectivity. One possible explanation is that the system has networking scripts or a network manager that relies on Python, and it got broken after `make install` replaced your default Python installation. It may be possible to fix this by reinstalling your RHEL Python packages (sorry, cannot offer more detailed help there, as I don't have access to a RHEL box).

I guess the lesson is "be careful about running `make install` as superuser". To easily install and manage different Python versions (separate from the system Python), the Anaconda Python distribution would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to undo that 3.6 installation and use the Software Collections version of python 3.6. See here for [python 3.6 installation](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world/#fndtn-python). Software Collections install "along side" the original versions so as to not affect the OS - and they are included in the subscription.

Comment: How would I 'undo' the installation to the point where it would revert the system? I have tried some tricks for reverting but nothing works.

Comment: "undo" was probably the wrong verb choice. Depending on what else you've put into this system, installing RHEL anew may be the most straightforward. But tbh, this is not my area.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of time slamming my head against the wall I got it worked out. My best guess is that the system (RHEL 7) relied on something from its default Python2.7 installation to handle SSL negotiations. Installing 3.6 alongside must have overwritten some pointer. Had I done this correctly, with `altinstall` all would have likely been fine.

The most frustrating part of this is that there were no error messages, connections just timed out.

To fix this, I had to uninstall all Python versions and then reinstalled Python2.7 - Once Python2 was back in the system it all seemed to work well.